# How can I pass arguments to my Java main method using run configuration arguments in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-interface

I'm using apache commons cli to parse the arguments.
The help outputs:

```
usage: Code Generation
-d,--delete           
-f,--factory <arg>    
-o,--output <arg>     
-p,--package <arg>    
-r,--reasoner <arg>
```

The arguments I'm trying to pass in the run configuration argument tab are:

-f "FactoryName" -o "~/MyFolder" -p "generatedcode"

The execution seems to stop because parsedOptions.getArgList().size() returns 0

The critical part of the parsing code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
CommandLine parsedOptions = parseArguments(args);
String outputFolderName = parsedOptions.getOptionValue("o");
File outputFolder = outputFolderName != null ? new File(outputFolderName) : new File("");
if (parsedOptions.getArgList().size() != 1) { // This should be false..
help();
System.exit(-1);
}
//Some other code
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should show a bit of the code that you're using to parse the options, that will save us a lot of guessing.

Comment: I edited the question and put some code there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at your Eclipse run configuration, you'll find a tab called "Arguments". There you can specify the arguments that should be passed to your program. See the [Eclipse manual](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-running_and_debugging.htm) for detailed information.

Afterwards, you're using `CommandLine.getArgList()` to check the number of arguments, but that is not really correct. Its [Javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getArgList%28%29) says:

> Retrieve any left-over non-recognized options and arguments

But if I understand you correctly, you want to see whether a specific option was given or not. For that, you probably want to take a look at [`hasOption()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#hasOption%28java.lang.String%29) or [`getOptionValue()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLine.html#getOptionValue%28char%29).

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't being clear there. It's in that tab that I passed the arguments
'-f "FactoryName" -o "~/MyFolder" -p "generatedcode"'
but it seems like there is a syntax error in there

Answer (score 1):

When you create run configurations, you will see Arguments tab which have following options:

1. Program Arguments - Give all your input parameters to program
2. VM Arguments - Here you can give memory arguments.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

After you startet you application in Eclipse you have a "Run Configuration".
Open the "Run Configuration" menü (easiest way is over the drop down menü on the green "run button".
Select the Run Configuration of your app.
Choose the second tab "Arguments" and enter your arguments into the input field on the top of the page.
Press apply and it should work. Test it with the debugger.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't being clear there. It's in that tab that I passed the arguments '-f "FactoryName" -o "~/MyFolder" -p "generatedcode"' but it seems like there is a syntax error in there